# [PHP][MYSQL] $_POST undefined index and cannot insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

Q1: I'm new to programming and have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: pimage in [..]

this is the code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="pimage">photo</label>
    <input type="file" name="pimage" id="fileToUpload"/><br />
    <input type="submit" name="psubmit" value="register" />
</form>
```

and this is my PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['psubmit'])) {
$image = $_POST['pimage'];
```

Q2: After the above code the form should be placed in a database, I don't get any errors but I don't see anything appearing in the database. Here is the PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['psubmit'])) {
    include 'opendb.php';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO new_products(Title, Price, CID,
Categorie, Sub-categorie, Description, Shipping) VALUES(:value1, :value2,
:value3, :value4, :value5, :value6, :value7)");
    $image = $_POST['pimage'];
    $values = array(
        'value1' => $_POST['ptitle'],
        'value2' => $_POST['pprice'],
        'value3' => $_POST['pcid'],
        'value4' => $_POST['pcat'],
        'value5' => $_POST['psubcat'],
        'value6' => $_POST['pdescription'],
        'value7' => $_POST['pshipping'], );

    $stmt->execute($values);
    $stmt->errorInfo();
}
```

great that this question is marked as a duplicated, but I don't see the awnser in the given link. I know what I have to set $_POST['pimage'] and as far as I know I did. I don't want to be the person that you need to feed the information but please give me the text in the given link so this piece of code is done.

Answer (score 1):

Just check out $_FILES global variable and small tutorial about uploading files [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

Your file name is here $_FILES["pimage"]["name"]. But you need to copy your file from temporary php path to yours server file folder with function move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pimage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file).

You have error in params biding, try this out:

```
if (isset($_POST['psubmit'])) {
    include 'opendb.php';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO new_products(Title, Price, CID,
    Categorie, Sub-categorie, Description, Shipping) VALUES(:value1, :value2,
    :value3, :value4, :value5, :value6, :value7)");

    $values = array(
        ':value1' => $_POST['ptitle'],
        ':value2' => $_POST['pprice'],
        ':value3' => $_POST['pcid'],
        ':value4' => $_POST['pcat'],
        ':value5' => $_POST['psubcat'],
        ':value6' => $_POST['pdescription'],
        ':value7' => $_POST['pshipping']);

    $stmt->execute($values);
    $stmt->errorInfo();
}
```

And there is no such variable as $_POST['pimage']. There is only $_FILES['pimage'].

Comment: This is what I have under the PHP code, but its never getting there (if()) because there is a undefined variable. if you want I can past the code somewhere.

Comment: Where do you have `$_FILES`?  All I see in your question is `$_POST`.

Comment: @JoeC, as I said above I have this after the above code. here is the full code:
http://pastebin.com/vKqH1ejG

Comment: You are not binding params here. Change "value1" to ":value1" and so on. Checkout [pdo statment docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

Comment: Thx for your comment Radoslaw, but sadly this was not full awnser, nothing is appearing in the database

Comment: Did you figured out what's wrong? I've edited my answer a bit. I hope this was the problem. If not, write about any errors you still recive.